# Get today date in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

How do I get the Today date on google appscript?

I need to write a code to input today´s date in a cell.

```
function changeDate(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(GA_CONFIG);
  var date = //Today´s date!?!?!!?
  var endDate = date;

  sheet.getRange(5, 2).setValue(endDate);

 }
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

You can change the format by doing swapping the values.

- dd = day(31)
- MM = Month(12) - Case sensitive
- yyyy = Year(2017)

```
function changeDate() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(GA_CONFIG);
    // You could use now Date(); on its own but it will not look nice.
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
    var endDate = date
}
```

Comment: Not really a good idea, the value returned by `Utilities.formatDate()` is a string, not a date object...you won't be able to do anything with it...  to change the display format in the cell while keeping the date object properties use [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) for full explanation and [this doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) as well

Answer (score 22):

The `Date` object is used to work with dates and times.

Date objects are created with `new Date()`

```
var now = new Date();
```

now - Current date and time object.

```
function changeDate() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(GA_CONFIG);
    var date = new Date();
    sheet.getRange(5, 2).setValue(date); 
}
```

Comment: this is a very bad idea, you are converting the date to a string then you loose all the date object properties in the sheet cell. And obviously you took this from a script you have that contains unnecessary parameters such as sheet name...

Comment: I have updated the script. Now I am not converting date object to string. I am getting exact date as 11/27/2017 11:05:01 in the cell. But  previous version of code with converting date object to string. I got full string of Mon Nov 27 2017 11:04:46 GMT+0530 (IST) of date. I didn't get any unnecessary parameters like sheet name as you mentioned. Kindly do correct me if I any thing wrong.

Comment: so, @Sergeinsas how to get today's date object ?

Comment: just like that : var date = new Date();

Comment: How would I set it to just the date, rather than the date and time? What's the best way of removing the time element?

Answer (score 9):

Google Apps Script is JavaScript, the date object is initiated with `new Date()` and all JavaScript methods apply, [see doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 5):

The following can be used to get the date:

```
function date_date() {
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;  if(month.toString().length==1){var month = 
'0'+month;}
var day = date.getDate(); if(day.toString().length==1){var day = '0'+day;}
var hour = date.getHours(); if(hour.toString().length==1){var hour = '0'+hour;}
var minu = date.getMinutes(); if(minu.toString().length==1){var minu = '0'+minu;}
var seco = date.getSeconds(); if(seco.toString().length==1){var seco = '0'+seco;}
var date = year+'·'+month+'·'+day+'·'+hour+'·'+minu+'·'+seco;
Logger.log(date);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetname = "DateEntry";//Sheet where you want to put the date
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
    // You could use now Date(); on its own but it will not look nice.
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    //var endDate = date;
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue(date); //Gets the last row which had value, and goes to the next empty row to put new values.
}
```

Comment: Please add some description about your answer, consider adding details related to a specific line or lines of code that you changed and why they need to be changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way, you can use javascript date object which is new Date().

```
function changeDate(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(GA_CONFIG);
  var date =  new Date();

  sheet.getRange(5, 2).setValue(date);

 }
```

But then you will get the whole time object. You just need to change the format in spreadsheet to time or date, whatever you like.