# How can I getValue in actual date format?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am running into an issue with getValue and the format it gives back in Google Sheets. The value in the cell is 2/19/2019 in format M/dd/yyyy in sheets but it is giving back **=Tue Feb 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)** (picture attached of issue). I am curious on how I can get the cell I am trying to fill to be the same format and look the same as 2/19/2019. Here is my code I am currently working on:

```
function fillDown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("spreadsheetName");
  var originRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1)
  var formula = originRange.getValue();
  targetRange.activate();
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(formula);
}
```

[image: Data sample]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894648/get-today-date-in-google-appscript did you see that?

Comment: @PéttrinMiranda Yes, that is specific to a cell's location where I am trying to add it to the end of the sheet, regardless of location. I was a little confused on merging these two ideas together, so I needed a little bit more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function fillDown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var originRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1)
  var value = originRange.getValue();
  var format = originRange.getNumberFormat()
  targetRange.activate();
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(value);
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
- [setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [SetNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I am curious if there is a way I can do that, but then have the targetRange be +1 (sorry if that's the wrong way to ask)? For example, instead of setting the cell to 2/19/2019, it would set it to 2/20/2019? My main goal behind this script is to pretty much add today's date into the last row, the targetCell.

Comment: If that was the main goal to this script, then why wasn't it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set a **formula** as the Date instead of the **value** of the cell. `getValue()` gives back the actual value of the cell, *not the formatted version*. A formula is different from both of these. If you want to set a date to a certain value and have it display in a specific, just use `setValue(date)` and **format** the cell.

```
var formula = originRange.getValue();
targetRange.activate();
// sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(formula); this results in the cell containing '=<date>'
sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(date);
```

***-->*** Make sure you **format** the whole column how you want and it'll display appropriately.

In summary, `setFormula()` **does not equal** setting the **format**.