# Trying to combine two working scripts does does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a quick macro to grab the current date and time and put it in a cell.  I want to make this a static time.  I made a quick macro by recording and it works as I recorded it, but when I ran the recorded macro it does nothing.  I am just doing a now function and then copying it and pasting the value on top.  If I split it into two separate macros, it works.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated.
"Timestamp" does not work.
"Now" works.
"copypaste" works.

'''

```
function TimeStamp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=now()');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};

function Now() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=now()');
  };

function copypaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

'''

Comment: Hi, I updated the existing answer in order to explain the causes of your issue, for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `date` object to return timestamp compared with using `=now` formula, which is faster and prevent script to skip your next line:

```
function TimeStamp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(new Date());
};
```

**Reference**

[Get today date in google appScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894648/get-today-date-in-google-appscript)

**Edit: Original issue**

In the original script, the script might not apply the changes after setting the formula `=now()` and before copy/paste, since spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance. So it's treating the active range as empty, and after pasting this empty value, the cell will remain empty.

To avoid that, you could have used [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) after setting the formula `=now()`.

Comment: The option PEH offered works perfectly.  It was still bothering me why what I was doing did not work.  Thank you Kin Siang & lambichus for explaining.