# Format plain text to date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

### Goal

Write a script that does the following:

- get data from sheet
- modify column to flip names from [Last, First] to [First Last]
- modify 2 columns to abbreviate company names & statuses
- write resulting data to another spreadsheet without changing the format
- add timestamp for when data copied

### Problem

I can get the data BUT it writes everything back as plain text. Thus instead of dates writing out as `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, they write out as something like this:
 *Mon Oct 19 2020 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)*

**Expectation:**
[screenshot of dates as "yyyy-MM-dd"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTXgq.jpg)

**Result:**
[screenshot of dates as whatever this garble is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4UMi.jpg)

I have googled extensively and can't seem to find a solution. I believe my problem is with using `toString()` in the Array.map. I'm not sure how to restrict the map method to only the columns that need modifying. Right now it affects the whole array.

(I used the code from [Google Apps Script for Multiple Find and Replace in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150450/google-apps-script-for-multiple-find-and-replace-in-google-sheets)  to write this part)

```
//-----FIND AND REPLACE FOR COMPANY & STATUS ABBREVIATIONS
function replaceInSheet(initArray, to_replace, replace_with){
  //Loop over rows in array
  for(var row in initArray ){
    //Use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = initArray[row].map(function(originalValue){
        return originalValue.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
      });

    //Replace the original row values with the replaced values
    initArray[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

**Question-->** How do I get the output of my script to format dates in two of my columns, correctly?

### Attempted Solutions that didn't work

- I tried swapping the name flip code to happen after the abbreviation code so I could add a `setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')` within the name flip for loop. I couldn't figure out how to apply this to columns within my array. Something like `initarray[x][5].setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`  gave me an error saying "TypeError: initArray[x](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#:%7E:text=setNote(note)-,setNumberFormat(numberFormat),-Sets%20the%20number).setNumberFormat is not a function"
- I tried adding code before (and then even after) `.setValues()` at the end to change the format. Some resources I referenced:

  - `setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')` from [stackoverflow: Set cell format with google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490800/set-cell-format-with-google-apps-script)
  - `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "yyyy-MM-dd")` from [stackoverflow: Get today date in google appScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894648/get-today-date-in-google-appscript)
  - [website post by BLACKCJ: "Cell Number Formatting with Google Apps Script"](https://www.blackcj.com/blog/2015/05/18/cell-number-formatting-with-google-apps-script/)
  - [google's developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#:%7E:text=setNote(note)-,setNumberFormat(numberFormat),-Sets%20the%20number)
  - and all sorts of other articles, blogs, forums, etc.
- I tried writing a completely separate function to change the format after my script runs. Nope. I can't get those 2 columns to format as dates

### Code & Sample Spreadsheet

Here's the whole code I'm using, modified to work with a sample google sheet I created just for the purposes of this question.

**Sample Google Sheet:** 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ys77hQHHajIo-Xaxyom0SVnyVMZ6bKOT8Smpadd2jv4/edit?usp=sharing

**Script:**

```
// ==================================================
// FUNCTION TO RUN
// ==================================================
function syncData(){
  //Ger Source Data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  var thisData = thisSheet.getRange("A4:M11");
  var initArray = thisData.getValues();

  //Get Target Location
  var toSheet = ss.getSheetByName("target");
  var toRange = toSheet.getRange("A4:M11"); //Range starts at A4

  //CHANGE [LAST, FIRST] TO [FIRST LAST]
  for (var x = 0; x < initArray.length; x++){
    var indexOfFirstComma = initArray[x][0].indexOf(", ");
    if(indexOfFirstComma >= 0){
      //If comma found, split and update values in the values array
      var lastAndFirst = initArray[x][0];
      //Update name value in array
      initArray[x][0] = lastAndFirst.slice(indexOfFirstComma + 2).trim() + " " + lastAndFirst.slice(0, indexOfFirstComma).trim();
    }
  }

  //ABBREVIATE COMPANY
  replaceInSheet(initArray, 'Bluffington School','BLF HS');
  replaceInSheet(initArray, 'Honker Burger','HBGR');
  replaceInSheet(initArray, 'Funky Town','FT');

  //ABBRIVIATE STATUS
  replaceInSheet(initArray, 'Regular','Staff');
  replaceInSheet(initArray, 'Contractual','Part');
  replaceInSheet(initArray, 'Temporary','Temp');
    
  //Clear Target Location
  var toClear = toSheet.getRange("A4:M11")
  toClear.clearContent();

  //Write updated array to target location
  toRange.setValues(initArray);

  //Write timestamp of when code was last run
  setTimeStamp(toSheet);
}


//-----FIND AND REPLACE FOR COMPANY & STATUS ABBREVIATIONS
function replaceInSheet(initArray, to_replace, replace_with){
  //Loop over rows in array
  for(var row in initArray ){
    //Use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = initArray[row].map(function(originalValue){
        return originalValue.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
      });

    //Replace the original row values with the replaced values
    initArray[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}


//-----ADD TIMESTAMP FOR WHEN THE SCRIPT LAST RAN
function setTimeStamp(toSheet) {
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "yyyy-MM-dd @ h:mm a");
  toSheet.getRange('F1').setValue(timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')` is a good solution but it's a method of a Range of the sheet. Not an array.

To apply the format you need to get a range first. Something like this:

```
toSheet.getRange('G4:G').setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

And there is one more thing ) Try to change this line:

```
var initArray = thisData.getValues();
```

to:

```
var initArray = thisData.getDisplayValues();
```

Comment: I tried pretty much that exact thing. I used `ss.getRange("G4:G11").setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` after line 41 in my code but it didn't change a thing. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: that seems to work! It even works when I comment out the line to `setNumberFormat()`. I'm not familiar with `getDisplayValues();` vs `getValues();` so I'll have to read up on why that worked, but thank you, thank you!

Comment: `getDisplayValues()` returns you a string. Not a Date object. Then you paste it back on the target sheet as is. Yes, probably you don't even need the format in this case after all.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks again!