# javascript: Remove time from datestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

I looked at the previous posts and suggestions but i cant seem to get it working.
For the moment this is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e){
var row = e.range.getRow();
var col = e.range.getColumn();
var width = e.range.getNumRows();
var startRow = 2 ;
var ws =  e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
var minDismount = 0 ;


if(col == 14 || col == 23 && row >= startRow && ws == "LOTO-A" && e.source.getActiveCell().getValue() > minDismount ){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,width).setValue(new Date());
}
```

it returns "20/03/2023 5:00:00"
I want to remove the "5:00:00"

Could someone please help me, i'm not a programmer so please be gentle.

Thank you

I tried `new Date(new Date().toDateString());` and `<any-date-object>.getDateWithoutTime();`

Comment: Have you tried `.setValue(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))`?

Comment: @Unmitigated yes that doesnt work, it still returns "20-3-2023 5:00:00"

Comment: Did you use that code exactly? Don't wrap it in a new Date. In any case, I can't reproduce the issue; it gives the correct result here: https://jsfiddle.net/yqemzwdo/

Comment: @Unmitigated: yes i see that it works with you. I tried again: if(col == 14 || col == 23 && row >= startRow && ws == "LOTO-A" && e.source.getActiveCell().getValue() > minDismount ){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,width).setValue(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
}
and it doesnt work with me.

Comment: Maybe you noticed but the code is running in a google sheet. When you adjust cell X then the datestamp occurs in cell Y (preferably without a time).

Answer (score -1):

```
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Comment: sorry doesnt work: '.setValue(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]);'

Comment: Can you check the value on the console? if(col == 14 || col == 23 && row >= startRow && ws == "LOTO-A" && e.source.getActiveCell().getValue() > minDismount ){
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  console.log(today);
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,width).setValue(today);
}

Comment: i'm really sorry but i dont know what you mean with console? I copied your latest code in the google apps script. It works but still gives the curren time "20-3-2023 17:10:06".
i understand it must be frustrating talking to a newbie...

Comment: All browsers have a developper console, are you running this code on a browser? Apparently not, I never heard of Google Apps Script, I don't know how to debug there.

Comment: You may look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894648/get-today-date-in-google-apps-script

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.